# How to check if user has different role in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on MVC4 project. My application has 3 different role. 
1. Admin
2. User
3. Superadmin

when admin logs in if he type direct page name in url for user page.. he is able to see user page also.

So how do i restrict role to see only his page.

I mean admin can see only admin pages,user can see only user page.. etc.

Comment: You can use `TempData[""].Depending upon tempdata[]  you can seperate view on pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the inbuilt role and membership providers, you simply have to use the authorize attribute:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
```

This can be attached to a controller or action.

Comment: no i am not using build in membership.. i have table which contains all 3 three role..anyways i am using session for roles.. but how do i send user to previous page when i check user has no role for this page ??

Comment: Unless you have a very good reason not to, I'd suggest you use forms authentication (http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/security/authenticating-users-with-forms-authentication-cs). By using session, your are bypassing all the inbuilt features which allow you to limit various pages to various roles.

Answer (score 0):

Use authorize attribute on action  as below .
[Authorize(Roles = Roles.Admin)]